# Edge.js library is not recognized by VS Code Poject

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, edge.js

I did the following:

1. Create a new console application in vscode using `dotnet new console`.
2. Add the Edge.js package using NuGet Add-Package command from vscode ctrl-shift-p
3. When writing the program as follows:

```
using System;
using EdgeJs;
...
```

I am getting the error:

`The type or namespace name 'EdgeJs' could not be found`

What I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the project was created using the default framework which is net50. According to the Edge.js package description, this is not supported. I changed it to net48 and it worked.